# MySQL - select interval of every 2 hours from timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you select every n-hours in a timestamp column? I am able to do so with 1 hour by grouping:

```
SELECT log_timestamp
FROM log
GROUP BY 
    DATE( log_timestamp ), 
    HOUR( log_timestamp )
```

Returns:

```
log_timestamp
2015-11-08 00:00:01
2015-11-08 01:00:01
2015-11-08 02:00:01
2015-11-08 03:00:01
...
```

Any ideas for how to do this by 2 or more hours?

```
log_timestamp
2015-11-08 00:00:01
2015-11-08 02:00:01
2015-11-08 04:00:01
2015-11-08 06:00:01
...
```

Comment: Maybe `SELECT L.log_timestamp
FROM log L
GROUP BY 
    DATE( log_timestamp ), hour( log_timestamp )/2`

Comment: @lad2025 floor(hour( log_timestamp )/2) or (hour( log_timestamp ) div 2)

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, I am from SQL Server world, I thought about Integer divison and in MySQL I need to use `DIV`.

Comment: @lad2025 make it an answer because it is a correct one.

Comment: @Shadow I've posted an answer. Refresh page :)

Comment: @lad2025 and I have upvoted it, although I messed up your nice 22222 reputation score doing so :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`INTEGER DIVISION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div):

```
SELECT L.log_timestamp 
FROM log L 
GROUP BY DATE( log_timestamp ), hour( log_timestamp ) DIV 2
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78f48e/3/0)**</kbd>

Comment: ive been trying different options and this helped me thank you

Comment: what should be the value of DIV if I need to group it by minutes? say 30 mins?

Comment: @hocuspocus31 Something like: [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1185c9/2/0)