# Select every N-hour interval from a table containing long time period

Tags: mysql

I have a column looks like below, 24-hour displayed from 2019 to 2021 :

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00
2019-01-01 01:00:00
2019-01-01 02:00:00
2019-01-01 03:00:00
2019-01-01 04:00:00
2019-01-01 05:00:00
2019-01-01 06:00:00
2019-01-01 07:00:00
2019-01-01 08:00:00
...
2019-01-02 00:00:00
2019-01-02 01:00:00
2019-01-02 02:00:00
2019-01-02 03:00:00
2019-01-02 04:00:00
2019-01-02 05:00:00
2019-01-02 06:00:00
2019-01-02 07:00:00
2019-01-02 08:00:00
...
```

How could I just select time points with every 4-hour interval?
What I expect is:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00
2019-01-01 04:00:00
2019-01-01 08:00:00
...
```

I tried some selections like:

```
select Time_UTC from t1
GROUP BY DATE(Time_UTC), hour(Time_UTC) DIV 4;
```

Just like this question: [MySQL - select interval of every 2 hours from timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270918/mysql-select-interval-of-every-2-hours-from-timestamp-column)

But it returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't1.Time_UTC' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I know there are some ways to lift the limitations. But I don't have access to do that.

Comment: Good job providing input and output.  What queries have you tried so we can help you debug it?

Comment: An RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data. This isn't that.

Comment: @Strawberry It's just one column in my whole table

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine, only with full Group by, you need to use an aggrgation function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1
>     (`Time_UTC` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO t1
>     (`Time_UTC`)
> VALUES
>     ('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 01:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 02:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 03:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 04:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 05:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 06:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 07:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-01 08:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 01:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 02:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 03:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 04:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 05:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 06:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 07:00:00'),
>     ('2019-01-02 08:00:00')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Time_UTC
> FROM (
> select MIN(Time_UTC) AS Time_UTC,DATE(Time_UTC) , hour(Time_UTC) DIV 4  
> from t1
> GROUP BY DATE(Time_UTC), (hour(Time_UTC) DIV 4)) t1
> ORDER BY Time_UTC;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Time_UTC            |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-01 04:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-02 04:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-02 08:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2547c45022a929b21f92e3ef9decdd55)*